# Why are reified generics hard to combine with higher-kinded types?

Tags: c#, generics, scala, language-agnostic, types

There exists a notion that combining reified generics with higher-kinded types is a hard problem.

Are there existing languages who have successfully combined these two type system features or is it not possible in general?

Is there any further information available to understand what has been done in this space until now?

Comment: Does c++ template count?

Comment: C++ doesn't really have that much of a runtime reflection system ... the question was more targeted to modern languages, but I have nothing against an answer from a C++ perpsective.

Comment: modern language != dynamic, and c++ do have RTTI (not reflection). My answer to this question is: just see how messy c++ template is :)

Comment: Just curious. What's the problem in combining them? An explanation or a link to one would be welcome.

Comment: @n.m: I tried to come up with a good link, but I couldn't find anything substantial, that's why I described it as "a notion" here ...

Comment: I know what higher kinded types are, but do not know what you mean by "reified generics". BTW, is it important that they are reified?

Comment: @Ingo: Yes. C# (and C++) have reified generics, all others out there do type erasure. People claim that higher-kinded types are only possible with non-reified generics...

Comment: This makes sense insofar as you could not "reify" the higher kinded parameter of a higher kinded type - it just is not a type itself. In Java, however, the generics do not allow for higher kinded types at all, despite it is erased at runtime.

Comment: @Ingo: I feel that you are on the right track. Could you create an answer about why it is not possible to reify the higher kinded parameter of a higher kinded type? Scala allows higher kinded types and runs on the JVM.

Comment: @soc: I'd rather not do that as I am unsure I am right. Regarding implementation of concepts of a a language (Scala) on a platform that itself does not explicitly supports those concepts: this is not an counterargument. To wit, C++ runs on bare metal which does not support any concept of types, leave alone their reification.

Answer (score 4):

For the second part of the question: Have a look at the [Scala programming language](http://www.scala-lang.org/) which has successfully combined reified generics from the underlying JVM with higher kinded types. The key concepts to make this work are [implicit parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114) and [Manifests](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html). A manifests is used to port some of the erased type information over to run time and implicits are used to inject the manifest in a type class like manner. The blog post [Manifests: Reified Types](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html) has more details.

Comment: Nope, Scala doesn't support reified generics. Manifests are only a partial workaround that you need to use explicitly.

Comment: I wonder then about Scala.NET - when .NET generics will be supported on that platform (they aren't yet - http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10299), maybe Scala will have reified generics (at least in part). That's not clear though - does .NET support higher-kinded generics? Will .NET code be able to use at least first-order Scala generics?

Comment: @Cedric, why do you call it a partial workaround? What limitations do you have in mind? The syntactic overhead is minimal: to reify the parameter `A` to function `def f[A]`, just use a context bound: `def f[A : Manifest]`. Since `A` is a type parameter that is reified as a run-time value of type `Manifest[A]`, I would call this a "reified generic". It's true that there's no JVM level support, and specialization of primitives does not happen automatically--is this what you mean?